# How to natively response multiple files to client in a single response

Tags: node.js, client-server, fs

I not familiar with server side development and node.js especially, but I need it for a web application that uses several `.css` and `.js` files. Simple web server should send those files per client request. I did it for `.html' file, but if I include`.js`files to`.html` it won't load to the page.

I think this is because of response headers that should be set correctly ? Or should I read in server side each file I want to response to client ?

server code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');    

var port = 8080;
var files = ["app.html", "math.js"];        
http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    fs.readFile('app.html', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        response.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
        response.end(data);
    });


}).listen(port);

console.log("listening on port: " + port);
```

app.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>| Demo1</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />


    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Loaded</h1>
        <h2>Loaded</h2>
        <h3>Loaded</h3>

        <canvas width="700" height="700" id="cnv"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="math.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**p.s.** please don't suggest any frameworks like express or modules that do all the work under the hood. I need to understand how to use node.js API for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this solution, I knew it needed to write some simple static web server

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 8080;

var appMainFileName = "app.html";
var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/jpeg",
    "png": "image/png",
    "js": "application/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"
};

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

  var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname,
    fileName = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);       

  fs.exists(fileName, function(exists) {
    if (!exists) {
      response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
      response.write("404 Not Found\n");
      response.end();
      return;
    }

    if (fs.statSync(fileName).isDirectory()) {
            fileName += '/' + appMainFileName;
        }

    fs.readFile(fileName, "binary", function(err, data) {
      if (err) {        
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(err + "\n");
        response.end();
        return;
      }

      response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": mimeTypes[ fileName.split(".")[1] ]});
      response.write(data, "binary");
      response.end();
    });
  });


}).listen(port);
```